# QDir::entryInfoList unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, qt4

My code is pretty simple:

```
void DirManagement::listFiles(QDir dir)
{
   QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoFilter, QDir::NoSort);
   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i)
   {
      QFileInfo fInfo = list.at(i);
      QString fPath = fInfo.absoluteFilePath();
      qDebug() << "# " << i << fPath;   }
}
```

The problem is that, if my directory path is: "/home/adasi/Desktop/GCUFolder"
this is the result:

```
#  0 "/home/Alya/Desktop/MCUFolder" 
#  1 "/home/Alya/Desktop" 
#  2 "/home/Alya/Desktop/MCUFolder/32Mon Oct 24 2011" 
#  3 "/home/Alya/Desktop/MCUFolder/32Sun Oct 23 2011"
```

However, What I am expecting is ONLY whats under the given directory:

```
#  0 "/home/Alya/Desktop/MCUFolder/32Mon Oct 24 2011" 
#  1 "/home/Alya/Desktop/MCUFolder/32Sun Oct 23 2011"
```

I tried most of the qt filters. Didn't work.

Comment: "/home/Alya/Desktop/MCUFolder/32Mon Oct 24 2011" is folder or file? Symlink maybe?

Answer (score 10):

Just to add more information
It worked like Mat said, specifying what you want to list, like this:

```
myQdirObject.entryInfoList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot, QDir::NoSort);
```

Comment: This is correct. simply passing QDir::NoDotAndDotDot will result in an empty list. it must be combined with another flag that specifies what you DO want (e.g., QDir::Dirs, QDir::Files, etc.).  Mat is totally correct in the supplemental comment to his answer, but this answer contains the complete code to achieve what the OP wants. Upvoting.

Comment: In a few words: if you use one flag, you have to fully specify filtering rules.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `QDir::NoDotAndDotDot` filter, this will remove the directory itself and its parent from the search.

Comment: similarly --> empty list Nothing has been listed!!

Comment: You need to specify what type of file you want in the list with `QDir::Files`, `QDir::Directories`, `QDir::Drives` or one of the combined constants.

Comment: what I need is the Folders, I tried  QDir::Files and QDir::Directories none of them worked!

Comment: That function works, I can't tell what your problem is without seeing the code you used, and what the permission an file types are on the stuff you're trying to list.

Answer (score 0):

The `entryInfoList` should be called with the `QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot` filter :

```
QFileInfoList list = dir.entryInfoList(QDir::NoDot | QDir::NoDotDot, QDir::NoSort);
```

Check the [corresponding Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qdir.html#Filter-enum) for more filters.

Comment: Mat gave basically the same answer 4 hours earlier. Try to read what others have written before you answer.

Comment: it doesn't work!! when I put this filter, I get an empty list!!